# ASP.NET MVC3 view with Cascading Dropdowns with 2nd and 3rd controls disabled until previous selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, cascadingdropdown

I have a view with cascading dropdown lists (3 to be precise)

the 2nd and 3rd are disabled until the previous option is selected and the jquery fires for it.

All this works great in a state where it's fresh.  I would like to use this same view when I have pre set values to pass to it. I have implemented this, to some degree, as I can set the values on the drop downs correctly, however the 2nd and 3rd dropdowns are disabled (since that's the initial state) and therefore do not pass the form field values on post.

Is there anyone who has implemented this kind of scenario successfully?  What am I missing to get the dropdowns state to be Enabled?

I need a way to remove the disabled option from the list (like it does when its fresh and selected on each dropdown)

Thanks.

Comment: A little code would be helpful. Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  if($("#DroprDownListID1").val() != "-SELECT-")
  {
    $("#DroprDownListID2").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the below method to enable and disable some values in cascading dropdown based on a condition. Please check whether it helps  you.

[Script]

```
       function SetdropDownData(sender, args) {           
            $('#ShipCity').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
            $('#ShipCountry').live('change', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Home/GetCities',
                    data: { Country: $('#ShipCountry').val() },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#ShipCity option').remove();
                        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                            if ($('#ShipCountry').val() == "Germany") {
                                $('#ShipCity').removeAttr('disabled')
                                var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                                $(optionTag).val(val.Value).text(val.Text);
                                $('#ShipCity').append(optionTag);
                            }
                            else {
                                var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                                $(optionTag).val(val.Value).text(val.Text);
                                $('#ShipCity').append(optionTag);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

}
```